# Run pre-integration-phase when running all tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I run all tests in IntelliJ for a maven project (right click on the project, `Run`, `All tests`) some integration tests fail because the `pre-integration-test` phase is not executed.

In my pom I have a maven plugin which is configured to run during the `pre-integration-test` phase. When I do `mvn verify` it gets executed before all the integration tests. But when I run it in IntelliJ it doesn't.

Any idea how to tell IntelliJ to run this phase?

Answer (score 3):

When you right-click > Run All tests, then not Maven is used but a normal JUnit (or whatever you use for your Tests) Runner is executed.

If you've already configured it in Maven, try running it from the maven view on the right side of Idea open "Maven Projects" > select *verify* (or any other phase) > push the green Play button at the top. (Multi-select is possible by pressing and holding the Ctrl-Button)

Alternatively you may execute a specific maven goal by editing the Run-Configuration (or even the default for Unit-Tests) and adding an entry in the *Before launch* section.

Comment: But when running it from the `Maven Projects` window I don't get this beautiful list of tests with the green checks on the left and the output for every test, right?

Comment: Correct. If you want that you should try to configure the maven goal as _before_-step in your Run-Config (see my last paragraph).